why sql server is not reusing plan in my adhoc query?
Seems my understanding of query plan is not correct.
If I run this query first time and check the query plan cache. I see one plan cached.
declare @codes varchar(max)='BHVD7,BHVDE,BHVDF'
SELECT OFST010020 AS [OFST010020], OFST730010 AS [OFST730010], Identifier AS [Identifier]   FROM STATIC_FUNDSHARECLASSUNIT_NEXT as f WITH(NOLOCK)  Inner join STATIC_FUNDSHARECLASSUNITEXTENSION_NEXT as fex WITH(NOLOCK) on fex.Identifier2 = f.Identifier    WHERE OFST900174 in (select value from string_split(@codes,','))

If I just change the code paramter and run the query again in the same SSMS window, for example
declare @codes varchar(max)='BHVD7,BHVDF'
SELECT OFST010020 AS [OFST010020], OFST730010 AS [OFST730010], Identifier AS [Identifier]   FROM STATIC_FUNDSHARECLASSUNIT_NEXT as f WITH(NOLOCK)  Inner join STATIC_FUNDSHARECLASSUNITEXTENSION_NEXT as fex WITH(NOLOCK) on fex.Identifier2 = f.Identifier    WHERE OFST900174 in (select value from string_split(@codes,',')) 

I thought the query plan would have 1 row and the useCount would be 2. But in the query plan cache, I actually saw two plans.
Each plan's sql text is actually the full text (starting with declare @codes). Am I doing something wrong or ad hoc query doesn't really re-use plan even parameter is involved?


Am I doing something wrong or ad hoc query doesn't really re-use plan even parameter is involved?

There is no parameter involved. You are using a local variable, not a parameter. There's not much difference in casual language, but to SQL Server they are entirely separate things.
In general, SQL Server does not reuse plans for ad hoc batches unless the entire text of the batch (not individual statements in the batch) matches exactly.
There are some subtleties when the statements within the batch can be parameterized on the server side via simple or forced parameterization but that doesn't seem to be the case here.
Regardless, even with server-side parameterization only the parameterized form will be cached and reused for different parameter values. The original ad hoc text is almost always cached separately and only reused on an exact match.
To encourage plan reuse, you need to use a stored procedure, prepared statement, or sp_executesql. All these allow you to explicitly parameterize your statements for plan reuse.
For more on parameterization and plan reuse see the Microsoft White Paper Plan Caching and Recompilation in SQL Server 2012.

Are you sure the two queries are the same (even the space location)?
I did a small test using the StackOverflow database.
Note: Cleaning up the stored procedure cache is not recommended in production:
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS;

I have the following query
DECLARE @PostTypeID AS int = 3;
SELECT * FROM dbo.Posts WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE PostTypeId = @PostTypeID

In the first execution, a new plan is created, the usecounts value is 1.
In the second execution, the plan is reused, the usecounts value is 2.
However, when I ran the query for the third time with a space in front, like this:
 DECLARE @PostTypeID AS int = 3;
SELECT * FROM dbo.Posts WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE PostTypeId = @PostTypeID

I received a different execution plan.

